# Plot Multiple DataFrames into one single plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataFrames that I would like to plot into a single graph. Here's a basic code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scenarios = ['scen-1', 'scen-2']

for index, item in enumerate(scenarios):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(4)})
    print df

df.plot()
plt.ylabel('y-label')
plt.xlabel('x-label')
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

However, this only plots the last dataFrame. If I use `pd.concat()` it plots one line with the combined values.
How can I plot two lines, one for the first dataFrame and one for the second one?

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you mean by two plots in one graph? What I understand is that you want two or more plots in one figure, am I right? But also I saw the comment you made to one of the answers that you want both plots as if it was one, and I don't seem to understand what you want. Do you want a graph were one 'x value' has multiple 'y values'? Like in a candlestick chart?

Comment: There's a question I have already answered about multiple plots in one figure, have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125674/how-to-read-multiple-csv-files-store-data-and-plot-in-one-figure-using-python/48130210?noredirect=1#comment83258912_48130210

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your plot in the for loop.

If you want them on a single plot then you need to use plot's `ax` kwarg to put them to plot on the same axis. Here I have created a fresh axis using `subplots` but this could be an already populated axis,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scenarios = ['scen-1', 'scen-2']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for index, item in enumerate(scenarios):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(4)})
    print df
    df.plot(ax=ax)

plt.ylabel('y-label')
plt.xlabel('x-label')
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. But putting `df.plot()` inside the loop yield two plots. I want both on the same plot.

Comment: @AdhySatya editted to include this - i see it in your question now :)

Comment: @josh that worked, thanks. I made a small fix, it should be `subplots()`

Answer (score 0):

The plot function is only called once, and as you say this is with the last value of `df`. Put `df.plot()` inside the loop.