# Plot graph from multiple CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have a project dir containing multiple sub-dir's. Each sub-dir contains a ***.csv** file with data  present in the following format

```
text,num,num
text,num,num
```

> Text in 0th row follows by numbers with ',' as delimiter

I wrote the code for plotting a **'*.csv'** file.

```
x = []
y_list= []
with open('d1_data.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(numpy.log10(float(row[1])))
        y_list.append(float(row[2]))
num = float(1000000)
new_y = [y / num for y in y_list]
plt.plot(x,new_y, marker='o')
plt.title('single_plot')
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
plt.show()
```

Instead, I would like to plot all the curves from each **'*.csv'** file present in different dir's into a single figure with same x and y axis. Each **'*.csv'** file values feed to the **'x'** list need to the **log10** of the actual value and the value to the **'y**' needs to be divided by **1000000**  as shown in the above sample code.

Could someone please help me with this implementation.

Comment: Also [How to read multiple CSV files, store data and plot in one figure, using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125674/how-to-read-multiple-csv-files-store-data-and-plot-in-one-figure-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

you can use glob to find all the files with *csv extenstions run a for loop for each one of them, and append each item to the list like you did in your code.

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
   *enter your code here*
```