# How to open multiple csv files from a folder in python?

Tags: python

I want to open multiple csv files in python, collate them and have python create a new file with the data from the multiple files reorganised...

Is there a way for me to read all the files from a single directory on my desktop and read them in python like this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, but you would have to write some code.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried specifying a path and writing for item in path: open etc etc but then it said it couldn't find one of the files and threw Errno 2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017003/extract-rows-and-filenames-from-multiple-csv-files

Comment: If you show us the code along with the full error, we can help you to fix it. But I cannot fix an error in a code I cannot see... Anyway, this site has rules or usages for what is expected for a good question: you really should read [ask].

Answer (score 8):

If you a have a directory containing your csv files, and they all have the extension `.csv`, then you could use, for example, `glob` and [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to read them all in and concatenate them into one csv file. For example, say you have a directory, like this:

```
csvfiles/one.csv
csvfiles/two.csv
```

where `one.csv` contains:

```
name,age

Keith,23
Jane,25
```

and `two.csv` contains:

```
name,age

Kylie,35
Jake,42
```

Then you could do the following in Python (you will need to install pandas with, e.g., `pip install pandas`):

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

# the path to your csv file directory
mycsvdir = 'csvdir'

# get all the csv files in that directory (assuming they have the extension .csv)
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(mycsvdir, '*.csv'))

# loop through the files and read them in with pandas
dataframes = []  # a list to hold all the individual pandas DataFrames
for csvfile in csvfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    dataframes.append(df)

# concatenate them all together
result = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

# print out to a new csv file
result.to_csv('all.csv')
```

Note that the output `csv` file will have an additional column at the front containing the index of the row. To avoid this you could instead use:

```
result.to_csv('all.csv', index=False)
```

You can see the documentation for the `to_csv()` method [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way to do what you want to do.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

os.chdir("C:\\your_path\\")
results = pd.DataFrame([])

for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("1*")):
    namedf = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=0, usecols=[1,2,3])
    results = results.append(namedf)

results.to_csv('C:\\your_path\\combinedfile.csv')
```

Notice this part: `glob("1*")`

This will look only for files that start with '1' in the name (1, 10, 100, etc).  If you want everything, change it to this: `glob("*")`

Sometimes it's necessary to merge all CSV files into a single CSV file, and sometimes you just want to merge some files that match a certain naming convention.  It's nice to have this feature!

Answer (score 0):

I know that the post is a little bit old, but using Glob can be quite expensive in terms of memory if you are trying to read large csv files, because you will store all that data into a list in then you'll still have to have enough memory to concatenate the dataframes inside that list into a dataframe with all the data. Sometimes this is not possible.

```
dir = 'directory path'
df= pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0,24):
  csvfile = pd.read_csv(dir+'/file name{i}.csv'.format(i), encoding = 'utf8')
  df = df.append(csvfile)
  del csvfile
```

So, in case your csv files have the same name and have some kind of number or string that differentiates them, you could just do a for loop trough the files and delete them after they are stored in a dataframe variable using pd.append! In this case all my csv files have the same name except they are numbered in a range that goes from 0 to 23.